# SFML 0x000007b Error When on Different Machine

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sfml

After compiling for release in Visual Studio, my application was successfully created and worked as intended on my machine. I tested it on my VM (same os/64 bit) and after launching it returned `The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)`. I had a friend test it and he got the same thing.

Assuming it's a DLL error, I have ran it through Dependency Walker and Process Monitor, but with my limited knowledge, I can't tell what is wrong (logs linked at bottom). The image below shows all of the DLLs I have linked in my folder.

[image: Game Folder]

I also just want to clarify again, that this runs on my computer with no errors. Thanks in advance.

Visual Studio Compile Log: https://pastebin.com/8TTPJxUC 
PML Log File (Process Monitor Log File): https://www.mediafire.com/file/udhuv6jgt8lfyoo/sfmlGameLogs.PML/file 
DWI Log File (Dependency Walker Image File) https://www.mediafire.com/file/p21r0oe0hbxlx5w/sfmlGameLogs.dwi/file

Comment: Use this program to tell you what dll is missing: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) could be caused by mixing 32 and 64 bit. Perhaps the other machine has a 32 bit version in the path of a dll you depend on but don't have in this folder.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks that worked and sorry for the late response. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Enable Loader Snaps and the system will give you the exact dependency that cannot be resolved. Assuming this is a dependency issue. 0x7B sounds more like a bug in code trying to produce a valid path name. Not uncommon for Open Source software to assume that every API uses POSIX file system conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to figure this out is the using the following replacement for depends to see if there is a missing `dll` in your install folder: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

The problem could be that the missing `dll` is found on the other system but is 32 bit instead of 64 bit.

The main reason for using the program I mentioned instead of depends is that Depends has false positives on modern systems.